# How to add tags for the words in the text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I need to implement text tagging. I have implemented a basic version when you can tag words or part of the sentence, but this approach does not work if you have 2 tags(Tag2 and Tag1) that cover the same word(picture below).
[image: Text tagging]

For Tag3, Tag4 I use:`<span style="border: solid 1px red;">Lorem Ipsum</span> the rest of the text...`
Could you please provide your ideas how to implement case with Tag2 and Tag1?

Comment: Any conditions? or selection? to this action....

Comment: These can only be solved by a triple tag system to have valid code at the end. Something like `<span class="green">text of</span><span class="green blue">the</span><span class="blue">printing</span>

Comment: use the range function in javascript

Comment: @HeinzSchilling Thank you for you answer. It is quite interesting, but will cause a lot of problems to style it.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to check your tags after processing and check for overlap. It would involve checking the start/end positions of the tagged items. Assuming you have some of this already available, here's some pseudocode to illustrate:

```
const taggedItems = [tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4];
/*
    assuming each item has this internal structure:
    {start: Number, end: Number}
*/

const overlapItems = [];

// sort and iterate tagged items
taggedItems
.sort((entryA,entryB) => entryA.start - entryB.start)
.forEach((entry,index) => {
  if(!index){
    continue;
  }
  // check for overlap

  if(checkOverlap(entry, taggedItems[index - 1])){
    if(!overlapItems.length){
      overlap.push([entry, taggedItems[index - 1]]);
      // check last overlap item
    } else {
      const lastOverlap = overlapItems[overlapItems.length -1];
      const lastOverlapEntry = lastOverlap[lastOverlap.length - 1];
      if(checkOverlap(entry, lastOverlapEntry)) {
        lastOverlap.push(entry);
      } else {
        overlapItems.push([entry, taggedItems[index - 1]]);
      }
    }
  }
});

function checkOverlap(entryA, entryB) {
    const partialOverlap = entryA.end < entryB.start;
    const fullOverlap = entryA.start === entryB.start && entryA.end === entryB.end;
    return partialOverlap || fullOverlap;
}
```

Running the above would create two array entries in overlap. The first array would contain tag1 and tag2, which from your illustration above have full overlap. The second array would contain tag3 and tag4 which partially overlap.

Afterward doing this process you can iterate over the overlap array and set styling for each group of overlapping items. The styling could be such that for each overlapped group it would be a box displaying the tag names within and some unique style to indicate it's a box with overlapping tags.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am looking for something else to display tags like on the picture. Actually I have implemented the solution: I have the transparent text for each tag and visible border. Then I have an effect that i see overlapped tags.